# Trying to understand behavior when freeing allocated memory

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I have code that functions like this:

```
void** array;
array = malloc(8*sizeof(void*));
```

And if I put, say, three elements into the array and try:

```
int i = 0;
for(i; i < 8; i++)
   free(array[i]);
```

It fails after 6 iterations of the loop. But if I populate the entire array (with 8 elements), the for loop executes just fine. I've tried this with 18 as well, and the loop fails after 9 iterations, but if I populate the whole thing it executes fine.

Can someone please explain what's happening here?

Comment: What elements are you placing into the array? You know that `free(array[i])` will not *initialize* `array` or something to that effect?

Comment: Your code is only performing one malloc() so it must only perform one free()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory returned by `malloc` is not initialized; it may contain garbage data.  You're allocating an array of pointers, but its initial contents are not valid pointers.  You're setting *some* of the items to (presumably) valid pointers, but leaving others uninitialized, and then you call `free` on *all* the items — even the uninitialized garbage ones.

You need to either:

- keep track of which items in the array have been set to a valid pointer, and call `free` only on those items, or
- explicitly initialize all the items to `NULL`.  This makes it safe to `free` them all, since `free(NULL)` is valid (and does nothing).

Answer (score 0):

Memory allocated for and assigned to *pointer to pointer* is of type *pointer* so as to assign further memory for the inner pointers to hold the actual data i.e `int**` is assigned with memory of `int*` so that `int`s can be assigned to the allocated `int*`:

```
// array is a double pointer variable
void **array = malloc(8 * sizeof *array);  // (1) allocate memory for 8 void* pointers
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
   array[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));
   // (2) - malloc for the actual data to be pointed by the above allocated pointers
```

then you've to do this for freeing the memory

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
   free(array[i]);                                  // undo (2)
free(array);                                        // undo (1)
```

You've to match every `malloc` with a `free`. Since you've done only 1, you should undo only 1.